# Python Regex to return AM from the following string

Tags: python, regex

My input is like this example:

```
hxxp://192.179.110.10:82/starvision.tk?server_time=6/12/2013 6:52:53 AM&hash_value=
```

I would like a python regex that returns the string between the 2nd blank space and the character `&`, in this example `AM`

Answer (score 1):

The expression is

```
hxxp[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^&]*)&
```

and the group 1 will contain your "am"

Comment: Thank You MK! My bad, I just showed a snippet of the code. There are several similar strings before and after the string I've included. Hence the regex needs to be specific to some of the parameters or identifiers included in this specific string. (i.e. some of the unique parameters are hxxp or server_time=, so the regex must reference those, else what you've suggested returns all strings in included between 2nd empty space and &, and there are plenty... THX

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\w+(?=&)', 'hxxp://192.179.110.10:82/starvision.tk?server_time=6/12/2013 6:52:53 AM&hash_value=')
['AM']
```

EDIT:

```
>>> re.findall('server_time=[^&]+?(\w+)&', 'hxxp://192.179.110.10:82/starvision.tk?server_time=6/12/2013 6:52:53 AM&hash_value=bcd&ddd=aaa')
['AM']
```

Comment: @CmoiCherie, function call is also expression;;  Do you just want `\w+(?=&)` ?

Comment: @CmoiCherie, I added another version which only extract server_time=... part.

Comment: Thanks Bro! That worked as well! Although what this server_time=[^&]+?(\w+)& returned is AM only and not the entire server time. Which is fine, coz that what I want not the whole server time. Cheers!

Comment: UPDATE: So both these expressions \&(.*?)\& AND server_time=[^&]+?(\w+)& return exactly what I want, namely, hash_value=4/MrNbXpByXWFm4ntUMSHg== for the 1st AND AM for the 2nd. BUT When I insert the RegEX in my XML file, each one RegEx must be enclosed in <>, so the issue becomes that the left < corrupts my RegEx and it becomes \&(.*?)\&< instead of just \&(.*?)\& Any idea how to get around that is greatly appreciated it. Even if press tab key after & to create a new space, the RegEx takes that new space into account and returns no match! I hope I didn't confuse the heck out of every one.

Comment: <regex>
<name>hxxp4</name>
<expres>\&(.*?)\&<expres>
<page>hxxp://itsallfree//free4all/tar/star.pxp</page>
<referer>hxxp://itsallfree.com/star2.hxml</referer>
</regex>
</item>